# summing column values in a row in a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to mysql. I am in need to sum the column values of he same row in table and update the summed value in the same table using mysql. Table name is Students

```
Name     roll_no    mark1      mark2     mark3      total    percentage
zxc      001         10          20        30         ?          ?
asd      002         20          30        50         ?          ?
```

I need mysql query to find total and percentage and update it in the corresponding columns. After doing this if I do `SELECT * from Students`. It has to display the following

```
Name     roll_no    mark1      mark2     mark3      total    percentage
zxc      001         10          20        30         60          60
asd      002         20          30        50         100         100
```

Comment: how are you calculating percentage ? What is difference between percentage and total ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those col values for total value and for percentage if I am correct for each subject 100 marks and to value is devides by 300 here(for 3 subjects)

```
SELECT roll_no, mark1, mark2,mark3,   
mark1+mark2+mark3 as total,(mark1+mark2+mark3)*100/300 percentage
    From students
```

But as per your logic percentage is something like below

```
SELECT roll_no, mark1, mark2,mark3,   
    mark1+mark2+mark3 as total,(mark1+mark2+mark3)*100/100 percentage
        From students
```

But first one seems more meaningful than latter

As per OP comments,  data should be updated in the columns

```
Update students set total=mark1+mark2+mark3, 
Percentage=(mark1+mark2+mark3)*100/300
```

Now select the table,  you will get calculated total  and percentage

Comment: But the values of percentage and total are not getting stored in database. It is just printing the total and percentage as per your explanation. Thank You

Comment: For that you need to update the values in that total and percentage columns